# User Input Value Not Kept In Form Input Field Using JS

Tags: javascript

I have a form that has an input field:

```
<input type="text" class="my-form" placeholder="0" maxlength="10" value="50">
```

Currently the value is 50. When I manually (using my keyboard) enter a different value, eg: 20 and press TAB key OR click anywhere on the webpage, the value is processed (eg: it might be multiplied by 2, this happens before pressing the submit button). This works fine.

When I try to use JS to change the value (in console):

```
document.querySelector('.my-form').value = 20;
```

The input field box gets updated to 20 (so far so good) however after this when I manually press TAB or click anywhere on the website nothing happens (unlike when I input the value manually), when I manually click on the input field, the value changes from 20 to 50 as if JS still had the old value which gives me reason to believe that the new value (20) which I changed to using JS is just displayed and not stored by JS.

Summary: The input value is just displayed in the text field and not maintained/held/kept by JS, when I click submit, it will change to the old value and submit that instead of the new value.

Comment: What are you using to submit?

Comment: Need more of the JS and HTML as a [mcve]

Comment: maybe hardcoing it into the html is a problem oO (I never tried that though)

Answer (score 0):

Check your other codes, it seams your problem is a side effect of them.

This demo works:

```js
function setValue(){
  document.querySelector('.my-form').value = 20;
}

function getValue(){
  console.log(document.querySelector('.my-form').value);
}

document.querySelector('#btnSet').addEventListener('click',setValue,false);
```

```html
<form onsubmit="getValue(); return false;">
   <input type="text" class="my-form" placeholder="0" maxlength="10" value="50">
   <input type="button" id="btnSet" value="set 20 Unit">
   <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Yes the setValue and getValue function sets and returns the new value, however after a few seconds of doing nothing the value is reset back to the old one, it is only maintained when i enter it manually, maybe I should create a click event in the input box first before setting the value?

Comment: @user3560827, Nothing dose not change the value of an input box in a web page else you enter a new value manually or your JavaScript codes change it. For this reason I said check your other `JS` codes. For example looking for all the `setTimeout` and `setInterval` keywords in your code and disable (comment) them temporary and test your page again. Generally I think some other parts of your `JS` codes (internal `JS` codes or some linked `JS` files to your page) are the reason of this issue. Try disable them and test again. Also press `F12` in Chrome and check the errors in the `Console` panel.